# how to access items in nested struct

Tags: c, struct, nested

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAXVALS 100

typedef struct {
    double x,y;
} location_t;

typedef struct {
    location_t loc;
    double sos;
} loc_sos_t;

int
main(int argc,char *argv[]){

int line_count = 0, i=0;
double temp_x, temp_y, temp_watt;


location_t loc_str[MAXVALS];
loc_sos_t sos_str[MAXVALS];

while (scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &temp_x, &temp_y, &temp_watt) == 3){
    loc_str[i].x   = temp_x;
    loc_str[i].y   = temp_y;
    sos_str[i].sos = temp_watt;

    i+=1;
    line_count+=1;}
for (i=0; i<5; i++){
    printf("x= %lf, y= %lf\n", sos_str[i].loc.x, sos_str[i].loc.y);

}
printf("line count = %d", line_count);
return 0;
}


input file
30.0 70.0 0.0045
53.0 63.0 0.0006
36.5 27.0 0.0005
70.0 25.0 0.0015
20.0 50.0 0.0008
columns are X coordinates, Y coordiantes, watts
```

i'm trying to read values from an input text file and putting them in 2 different structs. the first struct needs to have X and Y coordinates while the second one needs to have (X,Y) and watts. the last for loop is to check whether the values are there in the structs. when i try to access the X and Y coordinates from the second struct, it gives me zeroes. please tell me what went wrong, and how to fix it and if you're extra generous, how to improve my code so it's more elegant looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location_t loc_str[MAXVALS];
...
loc_str[i].x   = temp_x;
loc_str[i].y   = temp_y;
```

You're setting locations that have nothing to do with your sos_str array. Get rid of loc_str and do

```
sos_str[i].loc.x = temp_x;
sos_str[i].loc.y = temp_y;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do either

```
location_t loc_str[MAXVALS];
...
sos_str[i].loc.x = temp_x;
sos_str[i].loc.y = temp_y;
```

or

```
typedef struct {
    location_t *loc;
    double sos;
} loc_sos_t;
....
location_t loc_str[MAXVALS];
loc_sos_t sos_str[MAXVALS];
...
loc_str[i].x   = temp_x;
loc_str[i].y   = temp_y;
sos_str[i].sos = temp_watt;
sos_str[i].loc = &loc_str[i];
```

The second option adds unnecessary complexity but it helps to explain what went wrong in your code.
When you create the array sos_str, you actually create space to hold MAXVALS number of location_t as well. To access that space, you need sos_str[i].loc, just like the way you access any field in a struct.
In the second option, you need to create both arrays because loc_sos_t does not contain a location_t anymore. Instead, it contains a pointer to a location_t, whose memory needs to be allocated elsewhere. Having a pointer as a struct field is more common when the contained struct needs to be allocated dynamically.